# How do I remove and forestall all these 'SyncMaster' entries?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I assume the following 'SyncMaster' listings  to be from the Samsung SyncMaster 913v LCD monitor that I connect to my Windows 10 laptop with an VGA-HDMI adapter.

In the Sound > Playback window, I already right-clicked and unchecked  'Show Disconnected Devices' and 'Show Disabled Devices'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What **model** is the _laptop_, and do you connect VGA or HDMI to the laptop?

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad 320S.  HDMI.

Comment: What about the **adapter** model? Might be a "cheap/bad" one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to right click the playback device screen and uncheck **Show Disconnected Devices**, and see if they disappear. You can also try with *disabled devices*.

To get rid of them, you could check in **Device Manager**, if they also show up there and *uninstall* them. Make sure you enable **Show hidden devices**.

Comment: Make sure you enable **Show hidden devices**.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now, and added 2 more screenshots to my OP.

Comment: Then it's just to begin right-clicking and uninstalling, as a first step, to get rid of the existing ones :-)

Comment: But a new entry arises every time I turn on the computer.

Comment: Sure, but it will be easier to troubleshoot and see if it helps if you find a solution, if you just have one or a few of them, instead of al you have now.

Comment: But how can I eschew right-clicking and uninstalling' each entry? Is there a more efficient way to delete them all simultaneously?

Comment: You could do some scripting or _MAYBE_ delete them from the Registry, but that's always risky, so if it's just "only" 100, I thinks it's faster to just remove them manually. If it was 500 or 1000, it might be worth doing some automation. By the way, have you tried on the some other computer, if the same happens there? And do you have any warranty or can ask where you bought it?